# Selecting a Excel sheet based on number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to macros and VBA in Excel. Is there a way to check if the Testvalue is between Value 1 and Value 2, and move to the corresponding sheet? And if it's not, move to the next row and repeat.

E.g.
With the testvalue 3742 sheet A21 should be selected.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over each row until required condition is met:

```
Dim testVal As Long, r As Integer
Dim yourSheet As Worksheet
Set yourSheet = Sheet1
With yourSheet
  testVal = .Range("E2").Value
  r = 2
  Do Until (.Range("A" & r).Value <= testVal) And _
    (.Range("B" & r).Value >= testVal)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(.Range("C" & r).Value).Activate
    r = r + 1
  Loop
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! 
What is the reason for writing .Range and not just Range?

Comment: Because just using `Range`, it will refer to the acitve worksheet in the active workbook (which may be different from what the workbook you need). So, it's a good practice to refer to the worksheet with which macro should interact. I my example above it's `yourSheet.Range`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, instead of looping each row is faster if you use `Find` method.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngSearchA As Range, rngSearchB As Range, rngFoundA As Range, rngFoundB As Range
    Dim strValue As String, strSheetName As String
    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowB As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        strValue = .Range("E2").Value
        strSheetName = ""
        
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rngSearchA = .Range("A2:A" & LastRowA)
        Set rngSearchB = .Range("B2:B" & LastRowB)
        
        Set rngFoundA = rngSearchA.Find(strValue, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set rngFoundB = rngSearchB.Find(strValue, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not rngFoundA Is Nothing And Not rngFoundB Is Nothing Then
            If .Range("C" & rngFoundA.Row).Value <> .Range("C" & rngFoundB.Row).Value Then
                MsgBox "Searching value appears in both columns with different Sheet name."
            Else
                strSheetName = .Range("C" & rngFoundA.Row).Value
            End If
        ElseIf Not rngFoundA Is Nothing Or Not rngFoundB Is Nothing Then
            If Not rngFoundA Is Nothing Then
                strSheetName = .Range("C" & rngFoundA.Row).Value
            Else
                strSheetName = .Range("C" & rngFoundB.Row).Value
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Value not found!"
        End If
        
        If strSheetName <> "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Activate
        End If
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```